# Everything I need to file my design patent - application examples?

Tags: patent-applications, design-patent

I have been searching for an easy sample application for a design patent. I feel The USPTO is not really that good at providing an example filing application bundle. I will be filing as a Micro Entity and single inventor. **Are there any places / videos with a good example filing application bundle you know of?** There are a lot of documents to supply so I want to make sure I have them all. I will be filing on the EFS web online.

So far I have:

1. Drawings
2. Description of Drawings
3. Feature Description
4. Claim
5. Forms 8 , 17, 18, 15A

**Am I missing anything?**

This is the example of my description of drawings, claim, and feature description:

```
I, "name" have invented a new design for a "design title" as set forth in the following specification:

FIG. 1 is a northeast isometric view of a "design title" showing my new design;

FIG. 2 is a front view thereof;

FIG. 3 is a back view thereof;

FIG. 4 is a left view thereof;

FIG. 5 is a right view thereof;

FIG. 6 is a top view thereof; and

FIG. 7 is a bottom view thereof.


Feature Description: My "design title" is characterized by bla bla bla and it is used for bla bla bla

I claim: The ornamental design for a "design title" as shown.
```

Answer (score 3):

There are special requirements for the design drawings. You should definitely discuss the drawings with some draftsman who has previous experiences regarding design drawings. It is not good idea to use just examples because every patent application is different depending on what exactly and how do you need to protect.

Comment: Perhaps you mean “draftsman” instead of “craftsman”?

Comment: You are right. Corrected.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Thanks Mikk, that is a good idea, I'll try to find a pro to glance at my drawings!

Answer (score 1):

The USPTO has a [very good guide for design patents](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/design-patent-application-guide). One tip - be sure the lines are dark. I know someone who discovered that, as far as the USPTO was concerned, his drawings were all but blank.